# Entity framework Multiple Parent for a child

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

How can I implement a child that has multiple parents in Entity Framework?
The resulting tables must be as follows:

1.Courses:

```
CourseID int identity
CourseTitle nvarchar
.
.
.

OtherColumns as neede
```

2.CoursePreRequisites:

```
CourseID (FK to Course.CourseID)
PreRequisiteCourseID (FK to Course.CourseID)
```

or is there any better way to achieve multiple parent for a child record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need two navigation properties in the child class refering to the same parent class and - optionally - two corresponding foreign key properties:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; } // PK property
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
}

public class CoursePreRequisite
{
    public int CoursePreRequisiteID { get; set; } // PK property

    public int CourseID { get; set; }  // FK property 1
    public Course Course { get; set; } // Navigation property 1

    public int PreRequisiteCourseID { get; set; }  // FK property 2
    public Course PreRequisiteCourse { get; set; } // Navigation property 2
}
```

If one or both of the two relationships are optional, use `int?` instead of `int` for the foreign key properties.

If you use the property names as indicated in the example above you don't need to configure anything. EF will recognize the two one-to-many relationships by naming conventions.

You can also use collections as inverse properties in the `Course` entity if you need or want them:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; } // PK property
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CoursePreRequisite> PreRequisites1 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CoursePreRequisite> PreRequisites2 { get; set; }
}
```

However, in that case you must specify which navigation property pairs belong together in a relationship. You can do this with data annotations for example:

```
    [InverseProperty("Course")]
    public ICollection<CoursePreRequisite> PreRequisites1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("PreRequisiteCourse")]
    public ICollection<CoursePreRequisite> PreRequisites2 { get; set; }
```

Or with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasMany(c => c.PreRequisites1)
    .WithRequired(p => p.Course)      // Or WithOptional
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.CourseID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
    .HasMany(c => c.PreRequisites2)
    .WithRequired(p => p.PreRequisiteCourse)      // Or WithOptional
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.PreRequisiteCourseID);
```